# Android LeadBolt ad preload

Tags: android, leadbolt

I am trying to integrate LeadBolt SDK and I want to preload ad (Interstitial for example).
I mean I want to load an ad on app start and show it later, when I need (to avoid delays).
Is it possible?

For now it takes almost 10 seconds to load Interstitial.
I use LeadBolt SDK 6.0

```
myController = new AdController(this, "MY_LB_SECTION_ID", this);
myController.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the latest sdk 6.0.1 released today theree seem to be a new listener included.

```
    public void onAdCached() { 
 // Triggered when Ad is successfully cached 
 // now simply call loadAd() to display Ad when cached 
 ad.loadAd(); 
}
```

that could be what we are loking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am digging at this too but haven't figured it out yet. 
Want to show ad on exit, but it feels really silly to have users wait 10 sec to exit the app.